# How can I draw an arc (outline only) in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I draw a precise arc in illustrator, where only the edge shows?

**Example:**
In the picture below, you can see a circle, and part of that circle has a darker section (an arc).

There is a similar question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1741/how-to-draw-a-precise-circular-arc-in-adobe-illustrator), but the accepted answer will produce something like a pie slice, not just an arc segment like in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Draw a circle
2. Using the Pen Tool, add anchor points to both ends of your desired arc.
3. Using the Direct Selection Tool, select every point outside of your desired arc and delete.

[image]

Also worth noting that if you do have a "pie slice" you can simply delete the anchor point in the center of the pie and you will have your arc.

Comment: maybe cut is more appropriate

Comment: @joojaa probably yes